# Формат кириллицы в printf

Tags: php, printf

Приветствую,

при формате латиницы в printf проблем не возникает:

`printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "q");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "qw");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "qwe");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "qwer");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "qwert");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "qwerty");`

Вывод:

`q.........
qw........
qwe.......
qwer......
qwert.....
qwerty....`

Но когда дело доходит до кириллицы:

`printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "й");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "йц");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "йцу");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "йцук");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "йцуке");
printf("%'.-10s\r\n", "йцукен");`

Вывод:

`й........
йц......
йцу....
йцук..
йцуке
йцукен`

Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Просто буквы кириллицы занимают по 2 байта в utf8 Ищите ф-и для работы с многобайтными строками (обычно начинаются на mb_ )

Comment: @MDJHD, да, в курсе, что занимают 2 байта, но ведь вроде нет ф-и для работы с форматом как в printf для многобайтных строк. (не нашёл, по крайней мере)

Как временный костыль, дозаполняю строку пробелами циклом, похоже, костыль будет надолго.

Comment: Где-то (толи на stackoverflow, толи ещё где) встречал ссылку на библиотеку для укрощения utf8. Но где, и как называется -- не помню. Ищите и найдёте.

Comment: @froxxendsg, ну так можете попробовать ф-ю, что я вырыл в комментах на php.net в ответе внизу, имхо намного удобнее, чем каждый раз какие-то циклы изобретать для каждого конкретного случая

Comment: @MDJHD, перед отправкой того коммента ещё не видел Ваш ответ ниже. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел в инете такую реализацию:

```
<?php
/**
  * Formats string using sprintf, but correctly handles %s  with space paddings
  * 
  * uses conversion to iso-8859-2 and back
  * 
  * it is, however, much slower, so use only when needed!
  *
  * @param string $format
  */
function utf_8_sprintf ($format) {
   $args = func_get_args();

   for ($i = 1; $i < count($args); $i++) {
     $args [$i] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2', $args [$i]);
   }

   return iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args));
 }

// test

echo sprintf ("[%-20s]\n", 'escrzyaie'); //  how it should look without special chars
echo sprintf ("[%-20s]\n", 'ěščřžýáíé'); // not correctly handled by php
echo utf_8_sprintf ("[%-20s]\n", 'ěščřžýáíé'); // using above function

 /*
 produces:
 [escrzyaie           ]
 [ěščřžýáíé  ]
 [ěščřžýáíé           ]
 */

?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Этот костыль будет получше моего.

Кстати, для русских символов надо будет поменять стандарт на ISO-8859-5